# Error de plugin al crear proyecto spring boot desde cero en IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, spring, intellij-idea, boot

Creé un proyecto spring boot en IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2 pero no puedo iniciarlo, ni logra hacer build, me sale el siguiente error: `Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '3.0.6'] was not found in any of the following sources:`

También me pasa al intentar abrir un repositorio descargado.

Estoy usando un proxy pero ya lo configuré e incluso lo desactivé.

Tengo conexión a internet también.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.9.22'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.9.22'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa' version '1.9.22'
}

group = 'org.fung'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.withType(KotlinCompile) {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += '-Xjsr305=strict'
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

La versión de Java es 17 y concuerdan.

Después de correr el comando `gradle build`como mencionaron en el comentario recibo lo siguienteÑ

```
13:10:32: Executing 'build'...

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 145 ms
> Task :checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.9.22/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.9.22.pom, took 20 s 216 ms
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-daemon-embeddable/1.9.22/kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.9.22.pom

DemoApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:798
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:651
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177
                    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException at DataSourceProperties.java:186'.
```

Esto pasa tanto para proyectos creados desde cero como para proyectos ya creados que intento abrir.

Si se requiere más información por favor pedirla.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comprueba la versión de Java que tienes instalada haciendo un `java -version` en CMD y comprueba en el IDE en 'File-->Project Structure' que ambas coinciden con la versión 17 que estás especificando en el source compatibility.
Con las versiones igualadas yo lo solucioné.

Comment: Hola! Sí, las versiones concuerdan pero aún así sigo con el problema.

Comment: Intenta hacer el gradle build desde la CMD en vez de desde el Intellij, y luego haz un sync desde el IDE, espero que esto resuelva tu problema

Comment: Ya hice por CMD y me da otro error que lo dej{e en la descripción de la pregunta. Intentaré en otra PC a ver si puede tener algo que ver. Gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: Con el último error que has comentado tiene pinta de que te falta añadir la configuracion para acceder a la base de datos, echa un ojo a [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780094/spring-boot-default-test-throws-an-illegalstateexception)

Comment: Gracias! me faltaba agregar la configuración de la base de datos en el application.properties, también le agregué la dependencia para hibernate y ahí se solucionó el error.